# How to check version of V+ in adept

Tags: v+

I'm using adept version 3.0.3.11 currently. I am not able to use the instruction PROMPT to take inputs from keyboard in the V+ code. It says invalid instruction. The instruction is available according to the manuals for V+ version 11.3 and above. So I'm guessing my V+ version is older one.

Can anyone help me find the version of the V+ from adept ACE?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id` command. Specifically the real value function `id(1, 4)` will give you information about the system. You can find this information [here](http://www1.adept.com/main/KE/DATA/eV%20Plus/eV%20Language%20Reference/DL_Support/pdf_eV_redir.html), under the keyword id. Also if you use the `id` monitor command in the monitor window, you will get the following information:

[image]

Which includes the version information.